# Create a LayerDrawable object programmatically

Tags: android

How can I create this drawable programmatically?

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
    android:gravity="center" />
</item>
<item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp">
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_green"
    android:gravity="center" />
</item>
<item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp">
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_blue"
    android:gravity="center" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is pretty much completely described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#LayerDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable[])). Just create a new instance of `LayerDrawable` by passing its constructor an array of `Drawable` objects.

Comment: I'm interested in how to set the left, right, top, bottom parameters, and the gravity.

Comment: @Gratzi: Just read the reference page as all you need is in there ... always. Check it out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerInset(int, int, int, int, int)

Comment: `gravity` is a `BitmapDrawable` attribute, not a layer's. Therefore you must create a `BitmapDrawable` with and xml or programmatically and set this particular attribute.

Answer (score 19):

This wasn't too obvious until I read the comments under @OctavianDamiean's answer. His hyperlink is broken, but in order to programmatically set an `item`'s `android:top`, `android:bottom`, etc., reference `LayerDrawable`'s [`setLayerInset`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerInset%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method.

```
setLayerInset (int index, int l, int t, int r, int b)
```

`int index` - the index of the `Drawable` out of the `Drawable` array (that you passed in as the `LayerDrawable`'s constructor parameter) that you want to modify.

`int l, t, r, b` - Set these as you would in `android:left`, `android:top`, etc